# Склонение названий городов

Tags: лексика

Почему название города Афины, Канны или Саки склоняется по падежам, а Сочи - нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похожий вопрос уже был. Ответ на него такой. В Краткой русской грамматике в разделе "Несклоняемые существительные" говорится, что не склоняются иноязычные топонимы, оканчивающиеся на гласные (кроме -а, -ы), такие как: *Баку, Сухуми, Сочи, Хельсинки, Чили, Кале* и т.п. Иноязычные географические названия на -ы (слова pluralia tantum), такие как Афины, Канны, склоняются. Название *Саки*, хотя и имеет иноязычное происхождение, но давно обрусело, находится в зоне преимущественно русскоговорящего населения, поэтому склоняется, как, например, Жигули.

Comment: А в Сочи-то, наверное, русских вообще нет... Правилно вы говорите, но вот объяснения почему В "Саках", но в "Сочи" не наблюдается. Возможно потому, что Саки изначально восмпинималось как слово множественного числа, а Сочи почему-то до сих-тор остаётся с единственным числом. Хотя, видимо, и это пройдёт.